# How to blur an view using the new RenderEffect Library?

Tags: android, view, imageview, blur

Android introduced RenderEffect in the latest Android S.
How do i use this in my project?

Answer (score 2):

**RenderEffect** API only exits in API level 31 and succeeds. For earlier version compatibility, you have to work with **Bitmap**
Here is the very instructive group of blog post links [RenderEffect](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/rendereffect-blur/) and [Series of Image blurring](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/category/renderscript/); I believe it will be effective for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Works only on Android 12 as of now so is not a universal solution yet**

To blur a view

1 Set your target SDK and compile SDK to Android S in build.gradle

2.Use [Render Effect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RenderEffect)

3.set blur as follows

```
your_view.setRenderEffect(
     RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(
     30f, //radius X
     30f, //Radius Y
     Shader.TileMode.[X]// X=CLAMP,DECAL,MIRROR,REPEAT
)
```

4. The 4 types of blend mode are

CLAMP- Replicate the edge color if the shader draws outside of its original bounds

DECAL- Render the shader's image pixels only within its original bounds

MIRROR- Repeat the shader's image horizontally and vertically, alternating mirror images so that adjacent images always seam.

REPEAT - Repeat the shader's image horizontally and vertically.